# Convert multiple list columns to json array column in dataframe in pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame, it has multiple list columns and converts a JSON array column.

used below logic but not working any idea?

```
def test(test1,test2):
    d = {'data': [{'marks': a, 'grades': t} for a, t in zip(test1, test2)]}
    return d
```

UDF defined as an array type as below and tried to invoke in with column but does not work it out any idea?

```
arrayToMapUDF = udf(test ,ArrayType(StringType()))

df.withcolumn("jsonarraycolumn", arrayToMapUDF(col("col"),col("col2")))
```

| marks | grades |
| --- | --- |
| [100, 150, 200, 300, 400] | [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05] |

needs to be converted as below.

| marks | grades | Json-array-column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [100, 150, 200, 300, 400] | [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05] | {attribute:[{marks: 1000, |
|  | grades: 0.01}, |  |
|  | {marks: 15000, |  |
|  | grade: 0.02}, |  |
|  | {marks: 2000, |  |
|  | grades: 0.03} |  |
|  | ]} |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `StringType` because it's returning a JSON string, not an array of strings. You can also use `json.dumps` to convert the dictionary to a JSON string.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import json

def test(test1,test2):
    d = [{'amount': a, 'discount': t} for a, t in zip(test1, test2)]
    return json.dumps(d)

arrayToMapUDF = F.udf(test, StringType())

df2 = df.withColumn("jsonarraycolumn", arrayToMapUDF(F.col("amount"), F.col("discount")))

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|amount                         |discount                      |jsonarraycolumn                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1000, 15000, 2000, 3000, 4000]|[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]|[{"amount": 1000, "discount": 0.01}, {"amount": 15000, "discount": 0.02}, {"amount": 2000, "discount": 0.03}, {"amount": 3000, "discount": 0.04}, {"amount": 4000, "discount": 0.05}]|
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you don't want the quotes,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import json

def test(test1,test2):
    d = [{'amount': a, 'discount': t} for a, t in zip(test1, test2)]
    return json.dumps(d).replace('"', '')

arrayToMapUDF = F.udf(test, StringType())

df2 = df.withColumn("jsonarraycolumn", arrayToMapUDF(F.col("amount"), F.col("discount")))

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|amount                         |discount                      |jsonarraycolumn                                                                                                                                                  |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1000, 15000, 2000, 3000, 4000]|[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]|[{amount: 1000, discount: 0.01}, {amount: 15000, discount: 0.02}, {amount: 2000, discount: 0.03}, {amount: 3000, discount: 0.04}, {amount: 4000, discount: 0.05}]|
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you want a real JSON type column:

```
def test(test1,test2):
    d = [{'amount': a, 'discount': t} for a, t in zip(test1, test2)]
    return d

arrayToMapUDF = F.udf(test, 
    ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField('amount', StringType()), 
            StructField('discount', StringType())
        ])
    )
)

df2 = df.withColumn("jsonarraycolumn", arrayToMapUDF(F.col("amount"), F.col("discount")))

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|amount                         |discount                      |jsonarraycolumn                                                        |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1000, 15000, 2000, 3000, 4000]|[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]|[[1000, 0.01], [15000, 0.02], [2000, 0.03], [3000, 0.04], [4000, 0.05]]|
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+

df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- amount: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- discount: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
 |-- jsonarraycolumn: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- amount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- discount: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Maybe I confused you but the given solution is good. but when I write back to a database

Comment: Maybe I confused you but the given solution is good. but when I write back to a database as "attributes": "{\"attributes\": [{\"amount\": \"8000000\", \"discount\": \"0.01\"}  adding an extra char backslah and anslo attributes name is duplicate(since we mentioned as json) so i want to save data into database. I tried in way but no luck. def zip(xs, ys):
    return [{'amount': a, 'discount': t} for a, t zip(xs, ys)]
arrayToMapUDF = udf(zip ,(StructType([StructField('marks', IntegerType()),StructField('marks1', DecimalType())])))

Comment: without using dump JSON can we create an array with Key-value pairs?

Comment: @mike                                                                                                                                       def zip(xs, ys):
    return [{'amount': a, 'discount': t} for a, t zip(xs, ys)]
arrayToMapUDF = udf(zip ,(StructType([StructField('marks', IntegerType()),StructField('marks1', DecimalType())])))

Comment: jsoncolumn                                                                                                          [{"amount": 1000, "discount": 0.01},                                                                           {"amount": 15000, "discount": 0.02},                                                                      {"amount": 2000, "discount": 0.03},                                                                      
 {"amount": 3000, "discount": 0.04},                                                                       {"amount": 4000, "discount": 0.05}]

Comment: @john is my answer what you want?

Comment: **bold** @mike  the data stored as a string since we defined UDF as the string but I want to load as dict or JSON array.   i want to save the data as below.                                                                                                      ```  [{amount: 8000000}, {discount: 0.01}, {amount: 8000001}, {discount: 0.02}]   ```  **** but it stored as string like this since we define udf as string.****                                               ```  " [{amount: 8000000, discount: 0.01}, {amount: 8000001, discount: 0.02}] "   ```

Comment: @mike, thanks for the update code but i am getting the error message when i execute the code.                                                                                                                        
               ```                                                                                                                                        "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 622, in toInternal
    raise ValueError("Unexpected tuple %r with StructType" % obj)
ValueError: Unexpected tuple '[' with StructType
```

Comment: @john I can't reproduce this error on my side. Also this thread is getting too long - would you mind opening another question, including the code you used, the dataframe and the error you encountered? thanks

Comment: @sure mike i will do it. the code running fine but when i am trying to display(df) and am getting this error may be spark version or array type() declaration anyway i will create another thread for the same with my code.

Comment: @mike i have posted another question for the error.  here is the    title of the post is ```ValueError: Unexpected tuple '[' with StructType```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid using udf functions, you can use [high-order functions](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

transform_expr = "TRANSFORM(arrays_zip(amount, discount), value -> value)"
df = df.withColumn('jsonarraycolumn', f.to_json(f.expr(transform_expr)))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|amount                         |discount                      |jsonarraycolumn                                                                                                                                                             |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1000, 15000, 2000, 3000, 4000]|[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]|[{"amount":1000.0,"discount":0.01},{"amount":15000.0,"discount":0.02},{"amount":2000.0,"discount":0.03},{"amount":3000.0,"discount":0.04},{"amount":4000.0,"discount":0.05}]|
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: when I run the code, I am getting an error message.                                                                  ```Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input '->' expecting {')', ','}(line 1, pos 43)```

Comment: What's your spark version?

Comment: ```` Spark 2.4.5 ````

Comment: @john check my edit, I discovered how to run on spark 2.4.5 version

Comment: @ Kafels                                                                                                                     ```   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3566074724935406> in <module>
     12                    .withColumn("id", col("supplierName"))
---> 14 volumediscountDf = volumediscountDf.withColumn('jsonarraycolumn', to_json(expr(expr)))       TypeError: 'str' object is not callable   ```

Comment: You're overriding the `expr (pyspark.sql.functions)` function with `expr (str)` variable that I created. I updated my answer to avoid this behavior

Comment: ```i  changed as suggested but i getting the below error message.                                  .apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: &#39;col&#39;. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database &#39;default&#39;.; line 1 pos 21 ```

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html